# A function to put a text in div in several lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to implement an area to realise 3 essential tasks:

1. people can edit the text manually;
2. we could build a (JavaScript) function to put a text and display it in several lines with possible white spaces;
3. we could build a (JavaScript) function to color a part of the text given a position + a color. As a result, we may see different parts of the text in different colours.

I have checked some existing questions, it seems that `textarea` can NOT color a part of the text, which is a pity.

Someone suggests to use `<div contentEditable>`. I then implement this [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/futeho/11/edit?html,output).

So my first trouble is how to build the function to put a text in several lines. Unlike `textarea`, `$('#ce span').text("line1 \n    line2\n       line3")` ignores `\n` and white spaces, and still displays them in one line.

Could anyone help?

Additionally, Does anyone know any other solutions (that are not too complexe and realise the 3 essential tasks above, eg, in `JQuery`) than `<div contentEditable>`?

Comment: Are you trying to make a text editor?

Comment: Yes, but a simple text editor that can achieve the 3 tasks...

Comment: There are lots of pre-made text editors available. Some of them are opensource. So you could modify it to add your extra features. Why not try that way?

Comment: use css to make it look like a text area

Comment: @AkhileshBChandran I really want to make something very very simple, I don't know which pre-made text editor I could reduce... Or could you suggest some core JS or JQuery functions they use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to change from inputting text to inputting html into the editable div. Then you can give a class to each span around each line. Finally, run an `each()` JQuery statement to increment the left margin of each line:

```
$('#ce span').html("<span class='indented'>line1</span><br><span class='indented'>line2</span><br><span class='indented'>line3</span>");
    var indented = 0;
    $('.indented').each(function(index){
      $(this).css('marginLeft',indented);
      indented += 25;
    })
```

If you want to continue the margins for each line, it will be more complicated. You would have to create an event listener for when the user hits "Enter" or goes to the next line.

Here is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0om2ce5e/

**More Functionality**

If you want more functionality, you can just append an increasing number of spaces on each line. You will have to add an event listener for when the user goes to the next line:

```
$('#ce span').html("<span class='indented'>line1</span><br><span class='indented'>line2</span><br><span class='indented'>line3</span>");
    var indented = 0;
    $('.indented').each(function(index){
      spaces = "";
      for(var i = 0; i < index; i++){
        spaces += "&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp";
      }
      var origin = $(this).html();
      var newVal = spaces+origin;
      $(this).html(newVal);
    })
```

Here is the fiddle for this: https://jsfiddle.net/0om2ce5e/2/

Comment: Thank you for this... If you try to delete the indentation in the div, you will see something odd...

Comment: Additionally, the number of the white spaces in front of each line may be quite different. So we could see this input as an array of integer: `ws[0], ws[1], ws[2]` for `line0`, `line1`...

Comment: Look at the updated answer in terms of using a space character. You can use this and add some JS to it to get it to work how you need. Right now, it is doing it based on the index of each line. You have to add event listeners for when the user moves around the editable div.

Answer (score 1):

if you want the text to appear on separate lines you can use

```
    $('#ce').html("<span>line1<br>line2<br>line3");
```

instead. html will create the entire contents every time you run it and you can use tags inside.

to add 4 more spaces for each consecutive line this might work

```
    <script>
        $('#ce').html("<span>line1</span><br><span>line2</span><br><span>line3</span>");
        var spaces = '&nbsp;'.repeat(4),
            i = 2,
            spans = $('#ce').find('span').length;
        for (i; i <= spans; i++) {
          $('#ce').find('span:nth-of-type(' + i + ')').prepend(spaces.repeat(i - 1));
        }
    </script>
```

one more option to insert spaces after each break, so you don't need additional spans inside:

```
    <script>
        $('#ce').html("<span>line1<br>line2<br>line3</span>");
        var spaces = '&nbsp;'.repeat(4),
            i = 1,
            breaks = $('#ce').find('br').length;
        for (i; i <= breaks; i++) {
          $('<span>' + spaces.repeat(i) + '</span>').insertAfter($('#ce').find('br:nth-of-type(' + (i) + ')'))
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: I see, and how to realise the white spaces before `line2` and `line3`?

Comment: added the option which doesn't require additional spans inside, only break tags